# Measure to get a monthly count using weekly data

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

I have a payroll data table of the following form (sample data included at the end of the post).

```
[ Name, Date, Hours, Job Code ]

Name = Employee Name
Date = Date format, but this is weekly data. So the dates will always be exactly one week apart.
Hours = Number of hours worked for that Job Code for that week ending in the date specified in the [Date] column.
Job Code = Work type. Regular vs OT.
```

I am tasked with creating a table showing number of employees who've worked over a maximum per-week hours limit (60 hours), but in a monthly format. In other words, it should look like this:
[image]

There are a few important conditions:

- For the hours worked, must consider all pay codes. In other words, total hours per employee considering both regular and OT work hours.
- In the case of a certain employee working more than 60 hours/week two or more weeks in the same month (such as in the case of Jeremy in July in the data set below), still count that as only one entry per that month.
- The maximum calculation is strictly geater than (so exactly 60 hours a week doesn't count for above calculation).

I have created following measures so far:

```
// To get the total work hours considering all job codes for an employee for a particular date
HoursPerson = CALCULATE(SUM(WorkHours[Hours]), ALLSELECTED(WorkHours[Job Code]))
```

Then, I imagined I could create another measure where an employee's name is counted if `HoursPerson > 60`, and if I put this in a matrix it would give me the answer I want.

```
CountOver60 = COUNTAX(VALUES(WorkHours[Name]), [HoursPerson] > 60)
```

But this doesn't give me the expected answer, instead it counts all names that has at least one value. Below, I have put both measures in a matrix and highlighted HoursPerson > 60, and as you can see, for `CountOver60` it counts all names:
[image]

What am I doing wrong here? How can I get the desired result?

---

**Sample Data:**

```
Name,Date,Hours,Job Code
Alejandro,2023/08/04,25,REGULAR
Alexander,2023/07/14,20.5,REGULAR
Arceli,2023/09/15,30,REGULAR
Chad,2023/07/14,20,REGULAR
Chad,2023/09/15,21.25,REGULAR
Christopher,2023/08/11,27.5,REGULAR
Christopher,2023/08/18,43,REGULAR
Christopher,2023/08/25,31.75,REGULAR
Daniel,2023/07/21,22,REGULAR
Daniel,2023/08/04,23.5,REGULAR
Daniel,2023/08/11,70,REGULAR
Daniel,2023/08/18,28,REGULAR
Daniel,2023/09/01,21.5,REGULAR
Darrell,2023/09/15,29,REGULAR
David,2023/07/14,21,REGULAR
David,2023/09/01,21,REGULAR
Devin,2023/09/15,65,REGULAR
Everett,2023/07/21,21,REGULAR
Everett,2023/08/25,24.5,REGULAR
Gabriel,2023/08/04,47,REGULAR
Isaias,2023/09/15,20,REGULAR
James,2023/08/11,21.5,REGULAR
Jason,2023/07/21,29.5,REGULAR
Jason,2023/08/25,38.5,REGULAR
Jason,2023/08/25,30,OT
Jeremy,2023/07/14,63,REGULAR
Jeremy,2023/07/21,21,REGULAR
Jeremy,2023/07/28,67,REGULAR
John,2023/07/14,48,REGULAR
John,2023/07/21,28,REGULAR
John,2023/07/28,65,REGULAR
John,2023/08/04,24.5,REGULAR
John,2023/08/11,22,REGULAR
John,2023/08/25,20,REGULAR
John,2023/09/22,31.5,REGULAR
Justin,2023/09/15,31.25,REGULAR
Leonides,2023/08/18,20,REGULAR
Leonides,2023/08/25,22,REGULAR
Leonides,2023/08/25,42,OT
Mario,2023/07/21,22,REGULAR
Mario,2023/07/21,24,OT
Mario,2023/07/28,40,REGULAR
Mario,2023/07/28,24,OT
Matthew,2023/07/28,24.5,REGULAR
Pedro,2023/07/14,20,REGULAR
Robert,2023/08/18,20,REGULAR
Shawn,2023/08/04,24.5,REGULAR
Shawn,2023/09/15,32.75,REGULAR
Steven,2023/07/14,22.5,REGULAR
Thomas,2023/07/21,32,REGULAR
Thomas,2023/07/28,24.5,REGULAR
Thomas,2023/09/15,31.5,REGULAR
Thomas,2023/09/22,26.5,REGULAR
Thomas,2023/07/28,20,OT
Thomas,2023/08/18,45,REGULAR
Thomas,2023/08/18,20.5,OT
Timothy,2023/07/14,20,REGULAR
Timothy,2023/08/11,25,REGULAR
Timothy,2023/08/11,45,OT
Vincent,2023/07/07,20,REGULAR
Vincent,2023/07/28,20,REGULAR
Vincent,2023/08/11,20,REGULAR
Vincent,2023/08/18,20,REGULAR
Vincent,2023/09/01,20,REGULAR
Vincent,2023/09/08,54,REGULAR
Vincent,2023/09/15,65,REGULAR
Vincent,2023/09/22,20,REGULAR
```

---

**EDIT:**

Adding an image to provide an illustration of what needs to be counted.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE

[image]

```
CountOver60 = 
VAR t = 
FILTER(
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        SUMMARIZE(WorkHours, WorkHours[Name], 'Date'[Calendar Year], 'Date'[Month Number], 'Date'[Date]),
        "@x", [HoursPerson]
    ),
    [@x] > 60
)
VAR t2 = SUMMARIZE(t, WorkHours[Name], 'Date'[Month Number])
 
 RETURN COUNTROWS(t2)
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't quite work; two conditions that needs to be met are 1) for a particular month, an employee needs to be counted if they worked > 60 hours 'in a given week'. So, if an employee totalled more than sixty hours but never more than 60 hours in any of the weeks in the month, they shouldn't be counted. 2)  even if they did work more than 60 hours a week two or more weeks in a given month, they should only be counted once for that month.

Comment: So, for July, it's 3 (Jeremy, counted only once out of two, and John and Mario). August, 5 (Daniel, Jason, Leonides, Thomas, Timothy, once each). September, 2 (Devin and Vincent).

Comment: Here's an illustration of what needs to be counted. https://imgur.com/LeUGOvW

Comment: I'll update now.

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks! Do you mind explaining the calculation as well, particularly what SUMMARIZE does?

Comment: Summarise is creating a virtual table like the one in your screenshot. You can paste that part of the code into a calculated table to see the result. The first summarise, calculates the hours per person and then a filter retains anyone doing over 60 hours. The second summarise reduces this down to one row per name and month.

Comment: Got it, thanks! And marked as solved. Appreciate the help.